# How to split array in string in square bracket (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, explode

The form information is this string `[1,1x,1x,1x][2,2x,2x,2x]` this is two rownumbers.

This works for PHP 5.4+ i have 5.2:

```
$str = "[1,1x,1x,1x][2,2x,2x,2x]";
$arr = [];
preg_replace_callback('/\[(.*?)\]/', function($m) use (&$arr){
    $arr[] = explode(',',preg_replace('/([\w]+)/', "[$1]", $m[1]));
}, $str);
```

and this is the output:

```
Array {

  [0]=>Array {
      [0]=> "[1]" //rownumber
      [1]=> "[1x]"
      [2]=> "[1x]"
      [3]=> "[1x]"
  }
  [1]=>Array {
      [0]=> "[2]" //rownumber
      [1]=> "[2x]"
      [2]=> "[2x]"
      [3]=> "[2x]"
  }
  //etc
  [3]=>Array {
      [0]=> "[3]" //rownumber
      [1]=> "[3x]"
      [2]=> "[3x]"
      [3]=> "[3x]"
  }

}
```

**[Working demo](https://3v4l.org/MAO5h)**

Comment: Since you've tagged the question as *regex* and *explode* I presume you already know about the tools. You're expected to post some code to get help with it, not just dump your specs to get the job done for you.

Comment: i've read about explode and regex. But my knowledge is not so much. I think i need a correct regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `preg_replace_callback`, `explode` like as

```
$str = "[1,1x,1x,1x][2,2x,2x,2x]";
$arr = [];
preg_replace_callback('/\[(.*?)\]/', function($m) use (&$arr){
    $arr[] = explode(',',preg_replace('/([\w]+)/', "[$1]", $m[1]));
}, $str);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://3v4l.org/MAO5h)

Comment: if you replace "$arr = [];" with "$arr = "";" it works for PHP Version >5.3. And i have PHP Version 5.2.8 so it doesn't work. thank you for your time.